# Multiple choice Dynamic Choice Options in BotFramework Composer

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I try to create dynamic multiple choice in BotFramework Composer dialog. The idea is to fill choices from array like this *[“Java”, “Java Script”]*. With Dynamic choice options there is an input field with suggestion "String must contain an expression".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZMiy.png)I tried to use property with those data *user.techno*, but without success. Any suggestion on how to do it?

Comment: Can you show some of your code where you've tried to implement this and be more specific on what isn't working?

Answer (score -1):

Correct syntax of expression for multiple choice Dynamic Choice Options in BotFramework Composer is something like it:

```
{
  "$type": "Microsoft.ChoiceInput",
  "$designer": {
    "id": "851151",
    "name": "Multiple choice"
  },
  "prompt": "${bfdprompt-851151()}",
  "maxTurnCount": "3",
  "property": "user.technology",
  "alwaysPrompt": "true",
  "allowInterruptions": "false",
  "outputFormat": "value",
  "choices": "dialog.technologies",
  "appendChoices": "true",
  "defaultLocale": "en-us",
  "style": "HeroCard",
  "choiceOptions": {
    "inlineSeparator": ", ",
    "inlineOr": " or ",
    "inlineOrMore": ", or ",
    "includeNumbers": true
  },
  "recognizerOptions": {
    "noValue": false
  }
}
```

where property dialog.technologies contains an Array like this ["Java", "Java Script"].